# Symfony2 ManyToMany in different class entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have some entity classes which I want to share some common aspects. I have MagazineEntity and PublisherEntity. I want them to have, for example, a collection of links to other websites (the Magazine official page, it's wikipedia entry and some newssites referencing it, for example, and similarly for the Publisher).

To store those Links, since there would be many of them related to each entity, I thougth that I should create a OneToMany relationship from the Magazine with a new LinkEntity. But that would make it necesary to create another entity class for a PublisherLink, since the first LinkEntity would store the ID from the Magazine, that could be the same as a Publisher ID or a Issue ID. If not, this is what I would have:

```
Magazine: [ID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 1, Link: http://MagazineWebsite/, RelatedID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 3, Link: http://MagazineWebsite2/, RelatedID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 4, Link: http://MagazineWebsite3/, RelatedID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 7, Link: http://MagazineWebsite4/, RelatedID: 1]
```

So, if I use the same LinkEntity with a Publisher, It would store this:

```
Publisher: [ID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 2, Link: http://PublisherWebsite/, RelatedID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 5, Link: http://PublisherWebsite2/, RelatedID: 1]
LinkEntity: [ID: 6, Link: http://PublisherWebsite3/, RelatedID: 1]
```

So, when retrieving, I would end with all of them, since they aren't differentiated, but I want just the ones referencing my actual entity (be it a Publisher or a Magazine). The easy way should be then to add another field, like "RelatedType", which let me with the problem that I wouldn't know how to retrieve it from the original Magazine entity or Publisher entity.

How would be an optimized way of doing this?

Comment: The way you're explaining it sounds more like a OneToOne relationship? (one magazine has one magazine website, one publisher has one website, etc.). If you really want to store more links for any of those it's just a OneToMany relationship. You'd have a Link Entity and in your Magazine Entity a OneToMany relationship to the Link, same for Publisher and Issue. You're referencing the links from the Magazine/Issue/Publisher side, there's no need to differentiate them that way.

Comment: I haven't explained me then. I want to store many of them, yes, but I can't use just a simple OneToMany, since the related entity would have stored the same ID wether it reference a Magazine with ID 1 or a Publisher with ID 1, so I don't know how to differentiate them.

Comment: You've got your owning and inverse side of the relation the wrong way then. The resulting databse should look something like this: [Link](http://tinyurl.com/mlxgc9q). Try adding your relevant doctrine annotations / yml to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be using multiple JOIN tables, see Chapter 6.6 of [Doctrine Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) on Uni-Directional One-To-Many mapping.

The resulting annotations could look something like this (note that you should split your entities into several files, this is just for illustration of the ORM mapping annotations):

```
<?PHP

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Magazine")
 */
class Magazine
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link")
     * @JoinTable(name="Magazine_Links",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(name="Magazine_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(
     *              name="Link_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $links;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->links = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Issue")
 */
class Issue
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link")
     * @JoinTable(name="Issue_Links",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(name="Issue_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(
     *              name="Link_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $links;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Magazine")
     * @JoinColumn(name="magazine_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    protected $magazine;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->links = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Publisher")
 */
class Publisher
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Link")
     * @JoinTable(name="Publisher_Links",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(name="Publisher_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @JoinColumn(
     *              name="Link_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     *      )
     **/
    protected $links;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->links = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Link")
 */
class Link
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $uri;
}
?>
```